# Paypal IPN updating database with sandbox and simulator but not when "live"

Tags: php, mysql, paypal, paypal-ipn

```
<?php

 include 'MySQLCredentials.php';
 //read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
 $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
     $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
     $req .= "&$key=$value";
 }

 //post back to PayPal system to validate
 $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
 $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
 $header .= "Host: www.paypal.com\r\n"; //Change this to www.sandbox.paypal.com\r\n for testing
 $header .= "Connection: close\r\n";
 $header .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($req) . "\r\n\r\n";
 $fp = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);  //Change this to ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com for testing
 //

 //error connecting to paypal
 if (!$fp) {
     //
 }

 //successful connection
 if ($fp) {
     fputs ($fp, $header . $req);

     while (!feof($fp)) {
         $res = fgets ($fp, 1024);
         $res = trim($res); //NEW & IMPORTANT
         if (strcmp($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
             $transaction_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
             $payerid = $_POST['payer_id'];
             $firstname = $_POST['first_name'];
             $lastname = $_POST['last_name'];
             $payeremail = $_POST['payer_email'];
             $paymentdate = $_POST['payment_date'];
             $paymentstatus = $_POST['payment_status'];
             $mdate= date('Y-m-d h:i:s',strtotime($paymentdate));
             $otherstuff = json_encode($_POST);
             $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
             $conn = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbusername,$dbpassword);
             if ($conn->connect_error) {
                 trigger_error('Database connection failed: '  . $conn->connect_error, E_USER_ERROR);
             }
             // insert in our IPN record table
             $query = "INSERT INTO rustserver.ibn_table
             (itransaction_id,ipayerid,iname,iemail,itransaction_date, ipaymentstatus,ieverything_else,item_name)
             VALUES
             ('$transaction_id','$payerid','$firstname $lastname','$payeremail','$mdate','$paymentstatus','$otherstuff','$item_name')";
             $result = $conn->query($query);

             $conn->close();
         }

         if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
             //insert into DB in a table for bad payments for you to process later
         }
     }


     fclose($fp);
 }



 ?>
```

Basically my IPN works no errors... only odd thing is that when I go sandbox mode and test with simulator it receives IPN and is updating database..
But when I go "live" and test with legit payment in paypal I receive IPN but it's not updating database....

IPNListener :

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: It doesn't store errors somewhere in Xampp ?

Comment: Look at '$firstname $lastname',' and then iname - seems you need two fields there.

Comment: What you mean ? I added error logs and everything seems ok... strange but still not populating database when go live

Comment: Can someone change //post back to PayPal system to validate to CURL ?

Comment: Up Still a big problem!